# How to send the last sync time through the Fitbit Companion Messaging API to a clock face?

Tags: javascript, sdk, fitbit

The goal is to get the device.lastSyncTime from the companion `index.js` to the `app/index.js` in a Fitbit Sense clockface (SDK 6.0.0).

My simple idea was that the `tellSync()` function would send a message containing the `device.lastSyncTime`

```
function sendVal(data) {
  if (messaging.peerSocket.readyState === messaging.peerSocket.OPEN)
    messaging.peerSocket.send(data);
}

function tellSync() {
  let date = device.lastSyncTime;
  let data = {
    key: 'lastSync',
    newValue: date
  };
  sendVal(data);
}
```

However, within the app/index.js, the received message doesn't contain the `device.lastSyncTime`:

```
messaging.peerSocket.onmessage = evt => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(evt))
};
```

And the output is `App: {"data":{"key":"lastSync","newValue":{}}}`. There are no errors, it's connected to a current version Fitbit Sense device (2021-08-10) and a phone.

Now, if I put the `device.lastSyncTime` into a `console.log()`, it would hand me the timestamp (e.g. `Tue Aug 10 2021 19:59:40 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)` ), so I must be doing something wrong, but I'm not quite sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue of a data type. A modification of the tellSync() function fixed it:

```
newValue: device.lastSyncTime.toString()
```

The output is now as desired:

```
App: {"data":{
    "key":"lastSync",
    "newValue":"Tue Aug 10 2021 20:51:27 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)"}}`
```